# How to hide the click here to show more button using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do a simple task of making a text clickable to show more text . Like a more button.

```
<div 
onclick="document.getElementById('bio_1').style.display = document.getElementById('bio_1').style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';">
<h1>More</h1>
<div id="bio_1" style="display: none;">Member bio...</div>
</div>
```

Working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/qxj1xLj1/2/
What i want to do is when someone clicks the more button it will show the text and a hide button at the bottom. I am really inexperienced with javascript but i can follow it. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 handlers for "more" and "less" (get rid of the inline functions - they're hard to read and not meant for lengthy code)

```
document.getElementById("more").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("bio_1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("less").style.display = "block";

    this.style.display = "none";
}

document.getElementById("less").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("bio_1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("more").style.display = "block";

    this.style.display = "none";
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qxj1xLj1/5/

Comment: Why create another dom element when we can suffice with one?

Comment: I suppose - figured I'd create 2 since the "Less" button was supposed to be at the bottom of the text.

Comment: AFAIK, toggle buttons like this should remain at one place after state change to provide a better UX.

Comment: I see why you said to not use inline. I think the reason i had used inline was because i am using this code in a wordpress page and it doesn't do anything unless i make it inline. Any guidelines on how i would go about implementing it in the page. For reference this is the page http://rimowaedition.com/# . Section is artistic contributors. you can see on the fourth bio.

Comment: Would i be putting the script in a file and then calling it with the html already present on that page.

Comment: Yes, put the script in a JS file then create `script` tags with the source pointed to the JS file

Answer (score 0):

### [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qxj1xLj1/3/)

- Do not use inline event handlers. (`<elem onclick="something something"/>`)
- Use `addEventListener` to attach events, this gives you the freedom to add more event listeners later on without losing the original ones and provides flexibility over event bubbling and event wrapping.
- Use named functions as arguments.

P.S. I see that you have used ternary if. As a word of warning, don't use it when you require nested ifs.